# how to create a vector that contains the same generic function with different generic type?

Tags: generics, rust

how to create a vector that contains the same generic function with different generic type?

I wish the vector v contains function "decode<T:IE>(ie:&dyn IE)" with MyIEa, MyIEb, both implementing the IE trait.

```
pub fn test_ex7() {

    trait IE {}
    
    struct MyIEa {}
    impl IE for MyIEa {}
    
    struct MyIEb {}
    impl IE for MyIEb {}
    
    
    fn decode<T:IE>(ie: &dyn IE) -> T{
    
    }
    
    let v = vec![
        decode::<MyIEa>,
        decode::<MyIEb>,
    ];

}
```

mismatched types
expected struct `Box<[for<'r> fn(&'r (dyn IE + 'r)) {decode::<MyIEa>}], _>`
found struct `Box<[for<'r> fn(&'r (dyn IE + 'r)); 2], std::alloc::Global>`

Answer (score 1):

Add explicit type annotation:

```rust
let v: Vec<fn(&dyn IE)> = vec![
        decode::<MyIEa>,
        decode::<MyIEb>,
    ];
```

Comment: thanks! but how if the function like this:'fn decode<T:IE>(ie: &dyn IE)->T'

Comment: I don't think this could work, since `T` could be a different type for each element, and that would mean that each element has a different type, which is impossible.

Comment: But as long as you don't name any generic type in either function arguments or return type you are good to go.

Comment: If you have a finite set of functions you could try creating an enum with all possible types as it's variants and return that from your functions.